# Local Variables in same class, Sharing with functions

Tags: python-3.x

Why both codes below will give the same result if we  pass the variables (x,y) to the function and without passing it

## First Code

```
def gen(): 
    yield (x + y)
    yield (x - y)

x = int(input("X = "))
y = int(input("Y = "))
g = gen()
while True:
    try:
        print(next(g))
    except:
        print("END!")
        break
```

## Second Code

```
def gen(x,y): 
    yield (x + y)
    yield (x - y)

x = int(input("X = "))
y = int(input("Y = "))
g = gen(x,y)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(g))
    except:
        print("END!")
        break
```

Comment: Because in the first code example, `x` and `y` are defined as _global_ variables at the time `gen` is invoked. The first example will break if you change the names of `x` and `y`, though; the second example won't break because inside the definition of `gen`, `x` and `y` are _local_ variables.

Comment: Thanks for replying,
So in Python, the things going differently from other languages, is there any other comments on variable scope and definition would you provide?

Comment: Python tries to understand commands _at runtime_, as if you were executing one command after the other in an interactive terminal. This is why example 1 works, even though `x` and `y` are set in a line below the definition of `gen`. You shouldn't write code like that, though.